# How to save an image that is returned by UIImagePickerView Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an application, in which the user will select an image from a `UIImagePickerView`.

After selecting an image from it, I want to save it in my application.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
self.resumePreviousSettingAfterEditing = true;
[self.topImageView setImage:image];
[cubeModel setImage:image forFace:[cubeModel.validFaces objectAtIndex:selectedRowInFacePicker]];

[self dismissImagePickerAnimated:true];
```

}

You register an event in your controller to handle the image selection. In that event handler, call a method somewhere, say in your model to set the new image. That function would look something like this:

```
 (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)imageName {
    // get the image path
    NSString *filename = [self determineImagePath:imageName];

    // make sure the file is removed if it exists
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {
        if(NO == [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filename error:NULL]) {
        }
    }

    // Now, save the image to a file.
    if(NO == [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filename atomically:YES]) {
        [NSException raise:@"Image Save Failed" format:@"Unable to store image %s", filename]; 
    }
}
```

When you want to load the image again, you would so something like:

```
- (UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)imageName {
    NSString *filename = [self determineImagePath:imageName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    self.currentImage = nil;
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {

        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        self.currentImage = image;
    }
    return self.currentImage;
}
```

And don't get me started on transforming which is way harder than it should be.

Enjoy,
Jacob

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using SDK 3.0, here is some code to save the image into your application's documents folder:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    // Dismiss the picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Get the image from the result
    UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // Get the data for the image as a PNG
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    // Give a name to the file
    NSString* imageName = "MyImage.png";

    // Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
    // Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory,
    // or something similar.
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Now we get the full path to the file
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    // and then we write it out
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you will need to address when saving images returned by `UIImagePickerVIewController` is that writing the data to disk will almost always be unacceptably slow. Your UI will hang while the writing is occurring. So, you should *always* execute these types of operations in an asynchronous queue. Even if the performance seems good enough for your application when testing, *you should still do it an asynch queue* -- you never know what other processes the device might have going on which might slow the save down once your app is in the hands of users.

Newer versions of iOS make saving photos asynchronously really, really easy using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). The steps are:

1. Create an `NSBlockOperation` which saves the image
2. In the block operation's completion block, read the image from disk & display it (the only caveat here is that you must use the main queue to display the image: *all UI operations must occur on the main thread*).
3. Add the block operation to an operation queue and watch it go!

That's it. And here's the code:

```
// Grab the image
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

// Create a block operation with our saves
NSBlockOperation* saveOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{

   [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

}];

// Use the completion block to update our UI from the main queue
[saveOp setCompletionBlock:^{

   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ 

      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
      // TODO: Assign image to imageview

   }];
}];

// Kick off the operation, sit back, and relax. Go answer some stackoverflow
// questions or something.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:saveOp];
```

Once you are comfortable with this code pattern, you will find yourself using it a lot. It's incredibly useful when generating large datasets, long operations on load, etc. Essentially, any operation that makes your UI laggy in the least is a good candidate for this code. Just remember, you can't do anything to the UI while you aren't in the main queue and everything else is cake.